# Open-source CMS (Windows, .NET) recommendation

Tags: asp.net, windows, open-source, content-management-system

I am looking for an open source, Windows, .NET based, CMS. I have a few simple requirements:

1. Must run in or be built on the .NET 4 framework
2. Users must be able to automatically authenticate via IIS / integrated windows authentication
3. Must be able to utilize custom pre-built (existing) user controls presented as widgets / web parts / etc. with a minimum of re-coding.

I have looked through a handful of open source CMS projects with no luck so far. If anyone knows of a CMS that fits the bill I would really appreciate your insights. Thank you in advance for your help it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Download the web platform installer. You'll see a few good options in there - Umbraco comes to mind.

Comment: Please provide a list of CMS projects you've already considered.

Comment: I have looked at almost every .net based CMS in the platform installer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Umbraco](http://umbraco.org/)**

1. The latest release runs on .NET 4 ([Umbraco 4.5.2 for .NET 4](http://umbraco.codeplex.com/releases/view/51165))
2. [You can implement](http://forum.umbraco.org/yaf_postst8390_Need-to-implement-Integrated-Windows-Authentication-for-Members-and-Users-with-customization.aspx) Integrated Windows Authentication *(it's quite easy actually)*
3. Full support for [(.ascx) User Controls](http://www.nibble.be/?p=12%20%28) *(this is a godsend when you have existing user controls)*

Comment: +1 Although probably the shortest correct answer you'll get - it does satisfy all the requirements you listed :)

Comment: I really do like Umbraco quite alot, and in terms of how it handles user controls it's perfect. I have just read a bunch of forum posts about problems with AD authentication. Maybe this is not true though or isolated problems?

Comment: Hey Marko, thanks very much for the insight. I am going to do a "full on" test of umbraco. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Umbraco is the best out there! :-)

Answer (score 1):

take a look at MojoPortal :)  It's written in Object Oriented style with the simple standard layers ,

http://www.mojoportal.com/architecture.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can see a variety of choices from the Microsoft Web Platform Installer.
http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

Here is a .NET CMS that is under active development.
http://www.dotnetnuke.com/

You may however have to revisit your requirements.  They are not as simple as you might suppose.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I have been through just about all of the .net CMS offerings in the web platform installer, they do not seem fit my requirements. As for DNN from what I have read and I may be mistaken, it does not seem to consume "pre-built" user controls. Umbraco does do a good job of incorporating "pre-built" user controls but does not support integrated authentication as far as I can tell.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "pre-built" user controls?  Perhaps contrast it to what Ubraco does?

Comment: We have a bunch of user controls that are already built, we were using a pseudo home-grown CMS to house them. We would like to "dump" them into a real CMS without having to rewrite them. From what I have seem Umbraco does handle this very well, but from the little documentation / forum posts I have read though the Active Directory portion of Umbraco seems to have problems. Again I am only going by a very narrow subset of documentation / forum posts that I have seen.